# android listview message among two different layouts

Tags: android, listview

| have almost got my application working. Now i am in final stage. I am struck with an issue to display sent and received message in dynamic listview. Based on data sent or received i need to display the text in listview. I am able to view sent message in. I am able to receive the message from receiver but i am unable to display that in a listview.

sample code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
             View row;
             String query = null;
             // String even_color, odd_color;
             SharedPreferences prefList = getSharedPreferences("PrefsFile",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
             if(query == data){
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd,     parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView)     row.findViewById(R.id.text);
                textLabel.setText(data);
            }
             else
            {
                    row =     inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_even, parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView)     row.findViewById(R.id.text);
                textLabel.setText(datas);
            }
            return row;
        }
    }
```

If i sent message i need to display the msg in ie(list_row_layout_odd) and if i recieve message i need to display in (list_row_layout_even) layout.

please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd, null); ?

Comment: Thanks for response. But not working. I need to see both the layouts in same listview based on action(send nad receive). Any other idea..

Comment: please find the link below for logcat details.  http://pastebin.com/y1L3bQN9.. Thanks in advance.